# Evaluate the next limit

Tags: calculus

$\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\dfrac{3^x-1}{x}$. I was thinking use the logarithm since it's continous, use properties and then use the exponential but I'm not sure if there's an easier way.

Comment: Have you learned l'hosptials rule?

Comment: I know L'hopital but I cannot use it in the exercise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Without Using Derivatives**

Let $3^x-1=z$, $3=a$.

Note the fact that $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\dfrac{a^x-1}{x}=\lim\limits_{z\to 0}\dfrac{z}{\log_a(1+z)}=\lim\limits_{z\to 0}\dfrac{1}{\log_a{(1+z)^{\frac{1}{z}}}}=\dfrac{1}{\log_a{e}}=\ln a$, since we know that $\lim\limits_{z\to 0}(1+z)^{\frac{1}{z}}=e$.

Thus, the $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\dfrac{3^x-1}{x}=\ln 3$.

Comment: Pretty cool, thanks. :)

Comment: @Erick The same exercise was in my book as well, actually.

Answer (score 4):

I think this exercise belongs to the section of definition of derivative or closely related to it. Thus you can write it as: $L = \displaystyle \lim_{x\to 0} \dfrac{f(x) - f(0)}{x-0} = f'(0) = 3^x\ln 3|_{x=0}= \ln 3$, with $f(x) = 3^x$.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use $$A=\dfrac{3^x-1}{x}=\dfrac{e^{x\log(3)}-1}{x}$$ and use the fact that, for small values of $y$, $e^y\simeq 1+y$. Replacing $y$ by $x\log(3)$ will give $$A\approx \frac {1+x\log(3)-1}x=\log(3)$$

Comment: Unless I am mistaken sir, you were the one who answered my question here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1644126/memorizing-formulas-for-differentiation. It is nice to see you again.

Comment: It is also my pleasure to meet you again, be sure !